# Yii2 + другие сервисы + LDAP

Tags: php, yii2, ldap

Добрый день! У меня такой вопрос: есть несколько сайтов-сервисов написанных на PHP, один из них написанный мной на Yii2. Каждый такой сервис поддерживает LDAP аунтификацию. Можно ли сделать через LDAP единую точку авторизации и единый интерфейс создания пользователей?

Т.е. я в одном месте создаю пользователя и он потом может заходить и на сайт и в другие системы.

С LDAP практически не знаком, поэтому собственно и спрашиваю.

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можно ли сделать через LDAP единую точку авторизации и единый
>   интерфейс создания пользователей?

Да, можно.

Расширение http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php позволяет взаимодействовать с сервером каталогов по LDAP протоколу.

Если ваш сервер каталогов это Active Directory, то библиотека https://github.com/adldap/adLDAP упрощает работу с AD. Существует обёртка для использования adLDAP в качестве компонента Yii

Также обратите ваше внимание на библиотеку https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools. В [документации к ней](https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools/blob/master/docs/en/index.md) имеются примеры чтения, добавления, модификации и удаления объектов на сервере каталогов